# Django - option for public or private input

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am very new to django and I am developing a project, and I am trying to give users the choice of making their input public or not, as at the moment they can only see what they create. I was wondering how I would alter my model to give the user the option of choosing and if there is anything else that I need to change to include it in my form (probably forms.py and if so what do I want as the field)? Also, what would I need to change in my function.

This is my current model for it:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
```

And here is forms.py:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

This is what my function for it looks like:

```
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Thanks
Milo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying

> I am trying to give users the choice of making their input public or
>   not, as at the moment they can only see what they create.

If your description is correct and you want the user to choose whether the topic is public or not a  simple way is to put a `BooleanField` in your model and a checkbox in your form. So when the user checks the checkbox ,it would go public ,or not (if you want it in reverse).

But even if the user checks to be public you should filter you query.
I you have `Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user.pk)` your user would still see what he has created.

You would need something like `Topic.objects.filter(checked=true)`

Still this would mean that any user would see anything that has been checked as public from every user.

So,maybe you need two queries. One for the user to see whatever he has created and one for the checked as public.

Comment: What I am not sure about is what the checkbox code should look like - although this is very helpful